# How can I represent a 128bit integer in Java or C++?

Tags: java, c++, integer, 128-bit

Is it possible to have a 128bit integer in Java or C++?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the requirements you have. Just representing should be obviously possible: long a, b represents a 128-bit number as a pair of 64-bit ones.

Comment: @unwind: long might be 32 bits on some compilers.  `__int64` or `long long` will be at minimum 64 bits, but are non-standard extensions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [big integers in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815803/big-integers-in-c)

Comment: @Brian: correct, when I answered I was pretty sure this question was about Java only. For C++, use four uint32_t parts.

Comment: in g++ you can use these builtin types (at least on 64bits platforms): `__int128_t` and `__uint_128_t`.

Answer (score 17):

Of course you can represent them.

At *least* you can use a byte-array with 16 elements.

However, the question is if you just want to *represent* the value or actually do some *calculations* with it.

In Java you can use [`BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to represent (effectively) arbitrary sized integer values *and* do calculations as well.

Comment: C/C++ already has __int 128 https://gnu.huihoo.org/gcc/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html. U can use BigInteger for Byte with the same success. There are processors that support 128-bit values, and there are use-cases that use such numbers broadly like GUID or IPv6.

Comment: here is an answer which clarifies modern commodity CPUs capabilities https://stackoverflow.com/a/37925245/6713531. And here is Rust https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340308/how-does-rusts-128-bit-integer-i128-work-on-a-64-bit-system

Comment: C++ does not have `__int128`, but all the big compilers except MSVC add it as a custom extensions. The best is [`boost::multiprecision::int128_t`](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html)

Answer (score 14):

In Java, you can use the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class to store arbitrarily large integers. In C++ you can use a library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can. You will most likely need to use a library to do this though, at least for C++.

I like the [PolarSSL](http://www.polarssl.org) library or the [GNU MP Bignum](http://gmplib.org/) library.

Answer (score 1):

The `BigInteger` class is designed for integer values bigger then `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

**java.math.BigInteger**

To work with integers that are larger than 64 bits (the size of a long), use java.math.BigInteger. This class represents unbounded integers and provides a number of methods for doing arithmetic with them.

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/numbers/10biginteger.html

If you need decimal values use **BigDecimal**

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use **BigInteger** class in java.math package. 
This class provides operations for modular arithmetic, GCD calculation, primality testing, prime generation, bit manipulation like operations.

This class has been added in **JDK1.1** itself.

But I don't know there is such a availability built into with C++ library. There can be a extensible API from third parties.